# Using BizTalk flat file parsing engine outside of Biztalk

Tags: biztalk, flat-file

I need to build a custom `.net` app to parse flat files and extract data based on positions.

Is there a way to do this, using `Biztalk dll's` and `XSD schema's` .

Or is there another solution?

Answer (score 2):

Technically, sure.  There are some class instances you would have to fake and methods to override but it can be done.

You will still require a valid BizTalk license anywhere you would run this.

Comment: Thanks John.  Have you seen any documentation on the matter?

Comment: No docs, but if you understand the Pipeline API, it's not difficult to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You could use MapForce from Altova. They support flat file mapping. https://www.altova.com/mapforce/flat-file-mapping.html

The annoying thing is the flat file schema / XSD that BizTalk supports does not seem to be usable by any other system. Indeed my XSDs have what seem like BizTalk-specific things:

```
<schemaEditorExtension:schemaInfo namespaceAlias="b" extensionClass="Microsoft.BizTalk.FlatFileExtension.FlatFileExtension" standardName="Flat File" xmlns:schemaEditorExtension="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/SchemaEditorExtensions" />
```

On the plus side, MapForce is fairly easy to use, and can generate code for the mapping.

MapForce is not free, but they do have a trial available.